# Having problems with output

Tags: javascript, string, console

I build the code, which should return `Knick` if the number is odd, `Knack` if it's multiple of five and `KnickKnack` if it's either odd and multiple of five. The problem is that it returns line to line in console, I want it to concatenate in a string.

Here's the code:

```js
function knickKnack(maxValue) {
       
        const numbers = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <=100; i++) {
           if (i % 5 === 0 ) {
               console.log ('KnickKnack, ');
           } else if (i % 10 === 0) {
               console.log ('Knack, ');
           } else if (i % 2 === 1) {
               console.log ('Knick, ');
           } else {
               console.log (i + ', ');
           }
       }
       return numbers;
}

knickKnack();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function knickKnack(maxValue) {
    var knickKnackString = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
       if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 2 === 1)
            knickKnackString += 'KnickKnack, ';
       else if (i % 10 === 0)
            knickKnackString += 'Knack, ';
       else if (i % 2 === 1)
            knickKnackString += 'Knick, ';
       else
            knickKnackString += i + ', ';
    }
    console.log(knickKnackString);
}
```

Try like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is returning "undefined".

Comment: I don't understand what you want to return from the function since the array numbers are never modified ... If you just want to return the string and not print it just put return instead of the last console.log "return knickKnackString;"

Comment: Please add some explanation. Why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Comment: Thanks again, Girondi! I found why your solution didn't worked for me, it was something I was missing in the very beginning of the code! Your solution helped me to understand that I needed too to declare the string itself to concatenate!

Thank you very much!